# selenium file upload without <input type="file"> element

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7, selenium, automation

I'm trying to upload my resume using selenium/python over [here](https://boards.greenhouse.io/robinhood/jobs/996796#app) , under the Resume/CV Attach part.

When I inspect the Attach element, it shows up as `<a data-source="attach" href="#">Attach</a>.`

I'm not too familiar with HTML so I've tried finding the element by xpath, using `send_keys()` to upload the file but it runs through the program and doesn't upload anything. No error messages.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[10]/div/div[3]/a[1]').send_keys(info.resume)
```

I can manage to find the web element and use `click()` to open the upload file options up but I want to be able to fully upload a file.

It seems like the example online upload when the input `type="file"`, which I've used before and works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there is an input for file uploading. You can use below code:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('file').send_keys(info.resume)
```

Note that all 3 file input fields (CV, Cover letter and Unofficial copy of your transcript) have the same `id` attribute `"file"`, so you can select each by index:

```
driver.find_elements_by_id('file')[0].send_keys(info.resume)
driver.find_elements_by_id('file')[1].send_keys(info.cover_letter)
driver.find_elements_by_id('file')[2].send_keys(info.transcript)
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! How did you know the element id was 'file'? I couldn't seem to locate it on the html when I inspected the element

Comment: If there is a form for file upload then there definitely should be `<input type="file">` element. You can do `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="file"]').get_attribute('outerHTML')` to check how it looks like

Comment: Hm I see, so you knew that the element id  = 'file' because there is an option to upload the file?

Comment: No. I just know for sure that there is an input node. The attributes (including `@id`) I can get from outer HTML of element with `get_attribute('outerHTML')`